# How to wrap c++ object with boost.Python, so that Python will never call it destructor automatically

Tags: c++, python, boost

For example, I have C++ class "A", and python class "B". Class "A" wrapped with boost::python, so I can use it in my python code. Class "B" has a member of type "A", I create it in constructor of "B". When I remove my object of class "B", it automatically calls destructor of "A" in C++. I want to avoid this call, so that "B" will not be responsible for its member "A" (that is wrapped c++ object). So, I want to remove my "B" object, and still have "A" in memory.

Answer (score 0):

You should keep a pointer in your "B Class" to the "A Class object", So that when the "B object" is destructed the "Class A Object" is not reclaimed.

**EDIT:**

I think this could solve your problem:

```
aObjectPTR = POINTER(aObj)
```

Now, you have a pointer called "aObjectPTR".
place instead of "AObj" the name of your A Class Object.
After that, you have a pointer pointed to the A Class Object, so that the pointer(aObjectPTR) will only be reclaimed, not the object it point to.

Comment: How could I implement it with python and boost?

Comment: Thanks you for quick reply, but this doesn't help. When I wrote tmp = POINTER(MyClass(args...)), and debuggin in VS, I see that destructor of MyClass is called right after constructor.

Comment: @user733662: In your statment, you wrote "POINTER(MyClass(args...))", "MyClass(args...)" mean that you created a new object on fly, so it will be reclaimed when there is no reference left to it. And you must declare your pointer variable global in your class not in the constructor. and the reference to your AObject must be passed to the constructor of The B Class. And I think you should provide the code, so it could be easier to recognize the failure.